# Python Selenium: Chrome 57 version - WebDriverException: Message: Unknown Error

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click an webElement on my application using python Selenium in Chrome browser(Windows 7).

Python - 3.6 (64 bit)
Chrome - 57

```
from selenium import webdriver
#driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\Users\\ksahu\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.3.0\\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r".\\ChromeDriver.exe")
driver.get("http://192.168.209.902:98917/examinWeb/DummyLogin.jsp")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ID']//td[text()='TT']").click()
```

While running then I got the below error

```
File "D:/Automation/Python_WP/Excalibure_Automaion/TestingPurpose/Test01.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='isc_28']/table/tbody/tr/td[text()='Invoice']").click()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 249, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <td nowrap="true" class="tabTitle" align="center" valign="center">...</td> is not clickable at point (787, 57). Other element would receive the click: <img src="http://192.168.109.102:18217/examinWeb/isomorphic/skins/SilverWave/images/blank.gif" width="1600" height="1200" align="TEXTTOP" border="0" suppress="TRUE">
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Where as the same code is working in IE11..
Also I am able to click an web element in "google search page" in chrome 57

Why WebDriverException is coming in chrome(57 version and driver 29)? Selenium latest version I am using. I have added the error image.

[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7PGi.png)

Comment: Your error message doesn't match the code you posted. Please clarify the question and properly format the error message.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <td nowrap="true" class="tabTitle" align="center" valign="center">...</td> is not clickable at point (787, 57). Other element would receive the click: <img src="http://192.168.109.102:18217/examinWeb/isomorphic/skins/SilverWave/images/blank.gif" width="1600" height="1200" align="TEXTTOP" border="0" suppress="TRUE">
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: Why WebDriverException is coming in chrome(57 version and driver 29)? Selenium latest version I am using. I have added  the error image.

Comment: Please update the question with this additional information so everyone will see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page has a 'surprise overlay'. A modal.
It probably doesn't open in IE due to some internal scripting on the website's end.

Note the contents of the error message. It says that your intended element won't be getting the click (it's covered), and that the element who *will* get the click is 1600x1200 image called blank.gif.

These things can happen occasionally, on the website's side. Have you tried following your process manually, in Chrome?

Comment: In IE11 its working fine. 
Yes.. manually I have done it in Chrome and its working.